# ImGui errors : undefined reference to `ImmGetContext'

Tags: mingw, imgui

I am doing Imgui setup on DevC++. I took all the header and CPP files in imGui and added them to my Dev c++ project. Assigned the path to find them in the include directories.

When I try to compile i am getting following errors:
undefined reference to ImmGetContext' imgui.cpp:(.text+0x22d7b): undefined reference to ImmSetCompositionWindow'
imgui.cpp:(.text+0x22d8b): undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext'

Please help me with the setup.

Thank you.

Comment: You added header and cpp files, but you need a compiled library if you want to use the library, and link with that library (e.g. using `-l` linker flag and if needed `-L` to tell the linker where to find the `.a` file).